# Database model (entry and registration to the system)

Tags: database

First of all I want to attach the relational model

[image]

The objective of the diagram is:

1) a user when registering and when entering (attribute type in capture) his data must be stored.

2) a user can belong to an evaluation, in the evaluation their data must also be stored.

my question is in the INTENTO table, the INTENTO table will have a foreign key of the entity EVALUACION, and another foreign key of the entity CAPTURE.

my question 1: is it in case there is no id_evaluation to place in the INTENTO table?

my question 2: is it in case there is no id_capture to place in the INTENTO table?

Comment: For each EVALUACION record there should only be one INTENTO record and for each CAPTURE record there should only be one INTENTO record correct? They look to be marked as one to many relationships but I am wondering if they even need to be?

Comment: @JasonG. 
an evaluation should have many user attempts, and a capture should have only one attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current configuration the answer to both your questions is YES.

When a INTENTO (Attempt) record is created from a CAPTURE (Capture) it would only contain the CAPTURE foreign key and the EVALUACION (Evaluation) foreign key column would be empty or null.

When multiple Attempt records are created for an Evaluation they would contain the Evaluation foreign key and the Capture foreign key column would be empty or null.

This is generally not considered good database design. Instead I would store the Attempt data with the Evaluation or Capture data. So you would have a single Capture record for a User and multiple Evaluation records for a User.

Another option would be to store the Attempt data with the Capture record and only use the Attempt table for Evaluations. Then you could remove the Capture foreign key column.